# rearrange facet_wrap plots based on the points in the subplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, facet-wrap

I would like to rearrange the `facet_wrap` plots in a better way.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
freq <- sample(1:10, 20, replace = T)
labels <- sample(LETTERS, 20)
value <- paste("i",1:13,sep='')

lab <- rep(unlist(lapply(1:length(freq), function(x) rep(labels[x],freq[x]))),2)
ival <- rep(unlist(lapply(1:length(freq), function(x) value[1:freq[x]])),2)

df <- data.frame(lab, ival, type=c(rep('Type1',119),rep('Type2',119)),val=runif(238,0,1))


ggplot(df, aes(x=ival, y=val, col = type, group = type)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(aes(x=ival, y=val)) +
    facet_wrap( ~lab, ncol=3) + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.3)) + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits=paste('i',1:13,sep=''))
```

It results in the below plot:

[image]

Is there any way rearrange the plots based on their frequency? Some of the `lab` frequencies (or the number of points per type) are very low(`1-3`). I would like to arrange the plots `facet_wrap` wrt their frequencies instead of their label orders. One advantage is to reduce the plotting area and get better intuition from the plots.

Can it be done using the frequency values computed on the fly and passing them to the `facet_wrap`? Or it should be done separately using `dplyr` approaches and divide the data into low/medium/high frequent set of plots?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one idea. We can use `dplyr` to calculate the number of each group in `lab` and use `fct_reorder` from `forcats` to reorder the factor level.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(lab) %>%
  mutate(N = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(lab = fct_reorder(lab, N))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=ival, y=val, col = type, group = type)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=ival, y=val)) +
  facet_wrap( ~lab, ncol=3) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.3)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=paste('i',1:13,sep=''))
```

[image]

Set `.desc = TRUE` when using `fct_reorder` if you want to reverse the factor levels.

Comment: This is reordering the levels of the `lab` variable. It can also be done using baseR approaches. Is there any approach which would reduce the plot area by using it properly, minimalistic way. overriding the `x-axis` limits if there are no points available for it.

Comment: Alternatively, just create `N` and use good old `reorder` in the `facet_wrap` call, like `facet_wrap(~reorder(lab, N))`. Then `facet_wrap(~reorder(lab, -N))` will reverse it.

Comment: I meant this reorder the levels is the most appreciated approach.But, I am requesting if there is an approach which would reduce the plotting area by making use of the required area only. Or dividing the plot into subsets of plots based on their frequency. Basically, I am looking for approaches which would help in understanding the plots more easily. I have no specific method in mind.